# C# - if condition in Linq select query with where clause

Tags: c#, linq

How can I avoid If condition to this situation if userid is zero?

```
if (Userid == 0)
{
    var logList = service.GetLogDetails();
    var usernames = (from A in logList orderby A.FirstName select new { Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = A.Id }).Distinct();
    var loginDate = (from A in logList select A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();
    var logOutDate = (from A in logList select (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").ToString().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();
}
else
{
    var logList = service.GetLogDetails();
    var usernames = (from A in logList where A.Id == Userid orderby A.FirstName select new { Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = A.Id }).Distinct();
    var loginDate = (from A in logList where A.Id == Userid select A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();
    var logOutDate = (from A in logList where A.Id == Userid select (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").ToString().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: `where A.Id == Userid || Userid == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `||` in you linq `where` clause. Also you can improve by querying the `logList` once and then applying the different projections on it:

```
var logList = service.GetLogDetails()
                     .Where(item => Userid == 0 || item.Id = Userid)
                     .ToList();

var usernames = (from A in logList 
                 orderby A.FirstName 
                 select new { Name = $"{A.FirstName} {A.SurName}", ID = A.Id }).Distinct();

var loginDate = (from A in logList 
                 select A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();

var logOutDate = (from A in logList 
                  select (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").ToString().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Distinct();
```

Comment: I have written like this as you say

var logList = service.GetLogDetails().Where(item => item.Id == Userid || Userid == 0).ToList();

Now its working. Thanks

Comment: @AbhilashJA If his answer helped you, mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your queries like this

```
var usernames = (from A in logList where A.Id = UserId || UserId == 0 ...
```

Comment: Though correct this is like an answer posted 4 minutes ago